# Search Code in Project for Stored Procedures in the Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, file, search

Is there an easy way to run a search for all the stored procedures in the database to see if they are anywhere in C# code in Visual Studio?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 (C#) with SQL Server 2005.  I just want to query the database and return a list of all the stored procedures (I can easily do this). Then I want to search through an entire project to find which stored procedures are being used in the code, and which ones are not.

(Ok, as I write this out, I have an idea, but it involves looking though each file one at a time, which ain't bad, but I wonder if there is a better solution).

**EDIT:** It seems my question was not clear enough.  I want to get a list back of every stored procedure in the database that is not being called from code.  I am trying to remove all the unused code and database objects, so I need to know what is not used, and then start deleting.

Comment: Please do bear in mind that just becasue the user interface doesn't use the sp, doesn't mean it isn't being used by an SSIS package or a job or a different application or a dba. This gives you a list to check not a list to eliminate.

Comment: Oh, I know.  It is just first step in gathering a list of potential database objects to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a program to grab all the stored procedure names from the database.  I then read through all the files in my project manually, and check to see if they contained the stored procedure name.  If the name was not found in any files, I added it to a list.

I was hoping to find an easier way to do this, but this works for what I needed.

Comment: please upload to github I need to do this too! :D

Comment: pls upload if possible

Answer (score 4):

You can tick the "Use Regular Expressions" option in the "find in files" dialogue then separate the names with a | character.

To generate the pipe delimited list of procedure names to search for you can use

```
declare @list varchar(max)

select @list= isnull(@list + '|','') + name from sys.procedures

select @list AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')
```

To find stored procedures not referenced at all in your code you could look at a third party tool to do this such as [Apex SQL Clean](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_clean.aspx).

You might find that you can do all you need for now within the free trial period.

Comment: Thanks, I signed up for the trial, waiting for the welcome email.

Answer (score 2):

use a consistent naming convention, like usp_

Comment: we do ... but I need a list of all the stored procs not used in C# code

Comment: so you start with a list of all the stored procs in the c# code.  If you really want, you can write an app to read your code files and pull out references to the pattern you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the code is written.

You might be able to do a search for something like `.CommandText`.

Other things to search for might be just `SqlCommand` or `.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

Hopefully you might then get out all the lines that contains the name of a SP and then you might be able to use a regex or similar to get out just the SP names from the lines.